# Calling Derived class method which is private from Base class pointer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    public:
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"B";
    }
};

class D:public B
{
    private:
    void fun()
    {
        cout<<"D"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    D d;
    d.fun();//'error:virtual void D::fun()' is private
    B *b=new D();
    b->fun();//This Prints "D"
    return 0;
}
```

When I call fun() using derived class object I get compiler error.But why can I call D::fun() using base class pointer ?

Comment: *"why can I call `D::fun()` using base class pointer?"* Because `B::fun` is public, of course. It's unwise to reduce the access level of the override compared to the base class' function, precisely because it leads to counterintuitive outcomes like this (and is pointless anyway). By the way, you can call it on `d` via `static_cast<B&>(d).fun()`

Comment: Pretty normal behavior. `fun()` is declared as private in the context of `D`, but virtual and public in the context of `B`.